# Log client IP in apache access log when using reverse port forwarding

Tags: logging, port-forwarding, apache2

I have a home server which does not have public IP address (LTE internet), so I use another server which has a public IP for doing a reverse port forwarding.

I forward port 443 and 80 using following ssh parameters on my home server:

```
-R *:80:*:80 -R *:443:*:443
```

All works perfectly and my home server's website is reachable from the internet via public IP address. But I have one problem - I miss IP address of the clients in my apache access logs. Instead of the IP addresses I have there just entries with `::1` instead of the ip address:

```
::1 - - [11/Mar/2017:14:40:57 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 1775 "-" "-"
```

I think this is a result of the reverse port forwarding. I tried adding seeral parameters to apache's LogFormat configuration, but no success. Is there a way to have the client's real IP address logged in the apache acces logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the client IP address when forwarding via SSH tunnel. All your Apache sees is the remote IP of the TCP connection, which is the endpoint of your SSH tunnel.

In order to get the real client IP, you need to set up a reverse proxy on your server that has a public IP address, and then make it add the client IP in HTTP headers.

After that you need to add configuration to your Apache that includes the IP in HTTP headers to the log file.